# Do both a separate B and T lymphocyte need to be activated during the immune response?

Tags: immunology

Isn't it very unlikely that there will be both:
a) a B **and** a T with a receptor complementary to the antigen, and
b) that they will come into contact with the right antigen-presenting cell?

What would an immune response look like with only a B lymphocyte or a T lymphocyte activated? Is there any way for one class of lymphocytes to 'transfer' the complementary receptor to the other class?